# Associations not working with test entries

Tags: go, associations, go-gorm

I have two models User and Address in GORM defined:
File user.go

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Identity     string    `json:"identity"`
    Password     string    `json:"password"`
    Address      Address
    AddressID    int
}

type Address struct {
    gorm.Model
    Street       string `json:"street"`
    StreetNumber string `json:"streetnumber"`
}
```

In the main.go file I initiate the DB, automigrate and want to add a test user to the DB:

```
database.InitDatabase()

database.DBConn.AutoMigrate(&user.User{})
database.DBConn.AutoMigrate(&user.Address{})

userRec := &user.User{ Identity: "John Wayne", Password: "mysecretpassword", Address: user.Address{Street: "Teststreet", StreetNumber: "1"}}

database.DBConn.Create(userRec)
```

The user gets created and the address as well, however, the address is not associated with the user, just
empty Address fields come up. What did I forget?

Is this the normal way to setup a test entry if you have associations in your entities (with nested models)?

Comment: _the address is not associated with the user, just empty Address fields come up_ AddressID is not set in database ?

Comment: @Eklavya Yes, the AddressID in the user entry is set to default value (here 0). Why does it not assiociate with the genereated Address entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "address_id" field as a `foreignKey`.

for example

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Identity     string     `json:"identity"`
    Password     string     `json:"password"`
    Address      Address    `gorm:"foreignKey:address_id;association_autoupdate:false"`
    AddressID    uint       `json:"address_id"`
}
```

[Online documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html)

Maybe it will help.

Comment: Thank you @DonPepemon. This seems to get the right foreignKey into the AddressID field. However, when I want to query all users I don't get the associations delivered (just again default values for Address): `var users []user.User` and `database.DBConn.Find(&users)`.

Comment: nevermind. I tested to values in Insomnia as HTTP GET response and you explicitly included ` json:"-"` which deleted the nested object in the response of `c.json(users)`. Is there a reason why you added ` json:"-"` ?

Comment: This can be done easily with golang code, not just SQL queries. This is my mistake, json: "-" isn't needed here.

Comment: @Heikkisorsa "when I want to query all users I don't get the associations delivered" - You need to Preload (eager load) the association, by calling `database.DBConn.Preload("Address").Find(&users)`